# Markdown syntax does not correctly render certain tags (like [not]) in the preview

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, markdown-rendering

According to [the Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags), `[tag:not]` should format as a tag, but it doesn't in the preview while you are editing a post. What is wrong with the "not" tag?

- [not-a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-a-tag) is correctly formatted as a tag in both the preview and the rendered version, even though this is not a real tag.
- [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not) is not correctly formatted as a tag in the preview (as shown in the image below), even though is correctly formatted in the rendered view once posted.

[image: The "not" tag is not rendering as tag in the preview, even when the correct Markdown formatting is used]

Comment: Interesting. This also happens for `[tag:and]` and `[tag:or]`.

Comment: @Makyen yet `[tag:r]` works. As do `[tag:ro]`, as well as `[tag:adn]`  So, it's not related to length, it seems it's directly related to these keywords.

Comment: When you click "edit" here, and look at the preview, you see the tag being rendered, @Tom? I don't.

Comment: @CodyGray Somehow the whole "in the preview while you are editing a post" part flew right over my head. I see the bug as well.

Comment: @Tom Don't feel too bad. There was a whole deal at first where *nobody* understood what was going on, myself included. Thanks to the power of editing and comment-deletion, we were able to salvage the whole thing, and turn downvotes into upvotes.